# Javascript: Why is no error thrown when I call this code?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, canvas

I am playing around with the HTML canvas and write some text on it using Javascript.

While doing this I made a simple error which took me some time to find. I wrote:

```
context.fillText = ("My message", x-coord, y-coord);
```

The equal sign prevented the behavior I expected. But there is one thing I do not get: Why does this code not give me an error in the Javascript console of Chrome?

Is this valid Javascript? If yes: Could you explain whaat the code does when the equal sign is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is valid Javascript. It is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which just evaluates the expression on the left, then the one on the right and returns the value of the one on the right.

Since the expressions `"My message"` and `x-coord` have no side-effects, it is the same as:

```
context.fillText = y-coord;
```

Or:

```
"My message"; // Does nothing
x-coord;      // Does nothing
context.fillText = y-coord;
```

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that I did not even say "Thank You", so: Thank you for answering my question. I got it now and understand that operator :-)

Answer (score 4):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates each expression and returns the last, so the right hand side is evaluating to just:

```
y-coord
```

... and `context.fillText` is set equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the difference between

`context.fillText = ("My message", x-coord, y-coord);`

and

`context.fillText("My message", x-coord, y-coord);`

The answer is that you're assigning the expression to the right of the `=` sign to `context.fillText`, therefore attempting to overwrite the method itself, as opposed to invoking it with arguments.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, but I didn't downvote.

Comment: Fair enough, but no matter how many times I re-read the question, he doesn't ask about the comma operator any where, but asks what the equals sign is doing. And `context.fillText` is a function, so should be called with parentheses, not assigned to an expression...

Comment: Hi, your answer gives me another aspect of the answer so I up voted it. The solution I was looking for is the one above but still I wanted to thank for the different insight.